# How to modify a regex to exclude matching against a colon contained in a phrase surrounded by double quotes?

Tags: php, regex, icalendar

This is my current regex (used in parsing an **iCal** file):

```
/([^:]+)[:|(;)]([\w\W]*)/
```

The current output using `preg_match()` is this:

```
//Output 1
Array
(
    [0] => DTEND;TZID="Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London":20150601T073000
    [1] => DTEND;TZID="Greenwich Mean Time 
    [2] =>  Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London":20150601T073000
)
```

I would like to amend my regex to output this (i.e. ignore a colon if it is part of a phrase surrounded by double quotes - I think I need a lookbehind and there would only ever be one colon to find as it's a separator):

```
//Output 2
Array
(
    [0] => DTEND;TZID="Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London":20150601T073000
    [1] => DTEND;TZID="Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
    [2] => 20150601T073000
)
```

The semicolon in the regex is there because sometimes the colon I'm looking for might be on the next line due to multiple properties being defined (`;TZID="Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"`) so in this case I break on the semicolon. For info, the iCal file is read in one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(.*?)(?::(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|;(?=[^:]*$))([\w\W]*)
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/9

Comment: Thanks but looking for output exactly like the 'Output 2' snippet above

Comment: Thanks but where has the semicolon gone? I need that as a fallback if the colon can't be found as per my question description.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fix things - the semicolon is a fallback if a colon cannot be found. It's not correct to define `[:;]` because if the semicolon comes first it will use it rather than searching for a colon which is what I want to find. Semicolon is merely a fallback in the event the colon cannot be found so things don't break and I need to capture the semicolon if that is what is to be used (i.e. `(;)`). Appreciate your help

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted - it is the accepted answer

Comment: @u01jmg3 i have answered ur new question.do have a look :)

Comment: @u01jmg3 netime sir :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex based on a [SKIP-FAIL trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) that can safely match patterns outside of other patterns. However, I cannot find a 1-regex solution :(. You can use the main one to match colons outside the quoted strings, and if it fails to fetch you an array of more than 1 element, use another one:

```
"(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|:
```

And

```
 "(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;
```

The `"(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"` will safely match any escaped entities (if any).

```
$re = '#"(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|:#'; 
$str = "DTEND;TZID=\"Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London\":20150601T073000";
//$str = "DTEND;TZID=\"Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London\";20150601T07300001T073000"; 
$arr = preg_split($re, $str);
if (count($arr)>1){
  print_r($arr);
}
else {
 $re2 = '#"(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;#';
 $arr2 = preg_split($re2, $str);
 if (count($arr2)>1){
  print_r($arr2);
 }
 else {
  echo "No matches";
 }
}
```

[IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/3XrloZ)

And just another try (not sure):

```
"(?:[^"](?:\\.[^"]+)?)+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?!.*:);(?=[^:]*$)|(?!.*;):(?=[^;]*$)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR7bI6/7)

Comment: Thanks but demo gives no matches?

Comment: There is a match, the colon is matched. It is the colon that the string should be split against.

Comment: Thanks but the semicolon has gone? I need that as a fallback if the colon can't be found as per my question description. Sorry to make it more complicated.

Comment: It is not complicated, I am trying to look after my son, answer my wife's questions, and help you at the same time :) I will correct my answer ASAP.  I guess you want to split by a colon outside quoted substrings, but if there is no colon, use a semicolon outside of quoted substrings. Right? A sample string would greatly facilitate things.

Comment: Please check. If it is not what you ask, perhaps, we need more examples, or this is not a task for a regex... Or perhaps, your input is simple enough for vks' workaround.

Comment: Thanks for editing again - I prefer your (cleaner) approach with the SKIP-FAIL trick but for my current setup vks' workaround is enough for the input I am using. It outputs the matches for both the colon and semicolon in a manner my setup is expecting. Appreciate your help nonetheless

Comment: :) Great. Do not forget to upvote if an answer proved helpful/useful to you.